# "Index Patterns: Please specify a default index pattern" in Kibana

Tags: linux, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to create a simple hello world for ELK and be able to see kibana reports via the internet. I've installed kibana, logstash, nginx and elastic search. Here's my `/etc/logstash/conf.d/10-syslog.conf`:

```
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/var/log/*.log", "/var/log/messages", "/var/log/syslog" ]
    type => "syslog"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm able to access Kibana from the internet. However, I can see the reports because an error at Kibana when I'm clicking Dashboard, Visualize or Discover:

```
Index Patterns: Please specify a default index pattern
```

How exactly should I specify it? I just want to keep it simple for now.

Comment: Does [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286917/how-to-configure-index-pattern-in-kibana) help?

Comment: @dawud, no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Kibana uses "index patterns" to visualize the data stored in your elasticsearch indices.

You need to hit the elasticsearch restful endpoint and check what your indices are named by doing

```
curl -X GET <elasticsearchIP>:<elasticsearchport>/_cat/indices?v
```

This will list all the indices. Then, under kibana go to 
    management -> index patterns -> create index patterns

Here you write a regular expression that matches one or more of your elasticsearch indices. For example if your indices look like mine:

```
logstash-2018.10.29 
logstash-2018.11.14
```

you could write an index pattern called
    log*
and it would show data from from both of those logstash indices

Comment: Is there a way to establish the default index using curl, either to the elasticsearch REST API URL or to the kibana REST API URL?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Kibana -> Management -> Advanced Settings and fill the "defaultIndex" field.
Of course, it is necessary that this index exists at ES.